# How do I fix: Index exceeds the number of array elements (2)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm fairly new to Matlab and I've come across a program to show a dipole radiation pattern but when i tried running the program, the following error occurred.

> ```
> clear all
> clc
> format short g
> syms z theta lambda R
> prompt = 'Enter the frequency=? '; 
> freq = input(prompt);
> prompt = 'Enter the antenna size=? '; 
> length = input(prompt);
> L = round(length*freq/3e8,3)*lambda; %Length of antenna in terms of lambda
> k0 = 2*pi/lambda; %Phase constant
> z0 = 120*pi; %Intrinsic impedance
>
> I = sin(k0*(L/2-abs(z))); %Current distribution
>
> E(theta,lambda,R) = (1i*z0*k0*sin(theta)*exp(-1i*k0*R)/(4*pi*R))*int(I*2*cos(k0*z*cos(theta)),z,0,L/2); %E-field at farzone
> A=(1i*z0*k0*exp(-1i*k0*R)/(4*pi*R));
> p=(sin(theta)*int(I*2*cos(k0*z*cos(theta)),z,0,L/2)); %The theta part of the E-field with the constant term
> %Elimination the constant term from 'p'--%
> Q=(int(diff(p),theta));
> F= factor(Q,theta);
> field_pattern(theta) = simplify(p/F(1));
> %----------------------------------------%
>
> new(theta)=simplify(Q/F(1));
>  new2 = matlabFunction(new);
>  
> %------------------------------------------3D-pattern plot--------------------% 
> v=0.1:pi/499:1*pi;
> t=0:pi/499:2*pi;
> t2=0:pi/499:pi;
>
> [T,U] = meshgrid(t,v);
> [T2,U2]=meshgrid(t2,v);
> X = abs(new2(U)).*sin(U).*cos(T); 
> Y = abs(new2(U)).*sin(U).*sin(T); 
> Z = abs(new2(U)).*cos(U);
>
>
> X2 = abs(new2(U2)).*sin(U2).*cos(T2); 
> Y2 = abs(new2(U2)).*sin(U2).*sin(T2); 
> Z2 = abs(new2(U2)).*cos(U2);
>
>
> figure (1);
> surf(X,Y,Z,abs(new2(U)));
> shading interp
> axis vis3d
> axis equal
> lighting gouraud
> set(gca,'xtick',[])
> set(gca,'xticklabel',[])
> set(gca,'ytick',[])
> set(gca,'yticklabel',[])
> set(gca,'ztick',[])
> set(gca,'zticklabel',[])
> figure (2);
> surf(X2,Y2,Z2,abs(new2(U2)));
> shading interp
> axis vis3d
> axis equal
> lighting gouraud
> set(gca,'xtick',[])
> set(gca,'xticklabel',[])
> set(gca,'ytick',[])
> set(gca,'yticklabel',[])
> set(gca,'ztick',[])
> set(gca,'zticklabel',[])
> %---------------------------------E-field radiation pattern plot--------------%     
>  
> figure (3);
> theta3=0:0.01:2*pi;
>  
> polar(theta3,abs(field_pattern(theta3))); %E-field radiation pattern
> title(['Antenna length: ' num2str(round(length*freq/3e8,3))]);
> view([90 -90]);
> ```

-Error-

Error in sym/factor (line 107) multiplicity = double(c{k+1});

Error in dipole_pattern (line 20) F= factor(Q,theta);

I tried putting in the values as shown in the example (Freq: 3e8, Antenna size: 2.7) but the error came up while the example was able to produce the figure. What should i adjust to remove the error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in factor.m multiplicity is trying to access (k+1)th cell of c, where k max is numel(c). It should always throw an exception where c wont have (k+1)th cell. It could be a bug in original library.